# How to fake a call to MSMQ.Send

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, msmq, microsoft-fakes

I have the following test code:

```
 using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {                           

                // act
                sut.MethodCall();
            }
```

The SUT has the following method (for MethodCall):

```
  Dim mq As New MSMQ.MessageQueue(messageQPath)
  mq.Send(mqMsg)
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
  "The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation."
```

Obviously the queue won't exist and I won't have sufficient permissions if I don't have a queue created on the fake message queue.  Has anyone got any experience with working with MSMQ and Fakes so that the call to the MSMQ send is basically a no operation which I can verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shim needs to be set-up like so:

```
 ShimMessageQueue.AllInstances.SendObject = (m, o) =>
                {
                    // verification code here
                };
```

As Fakes doesn't have concept of verifying a call directly using the framework, you just put the verification code inside the lambda for the SendObject call.